# What are the concrete disadvantages of re-binding a var in a Clojure function?

Tags: clojure

While exploring various ways of computing factorials in Clojure, I came up with the following (non-idiomatic) function:

```lisp
(defn factorial-using-do-dotimes [x]
  (do
    (def a 1)
    (dotimes [i x]
      (def a (* a (inc i)))))
  a)
```

REPL:

```lisp
user=> (factorial-using-do-dotimes 5)
120
```

What are the concrete disadvantages of this (aside from "non-idiomatic")? Performance? Correctness (that is, possible defects)?

Comment: The approach given here has obvious correctness bugs, to the point that there's little need to address them. A better question (one with a less-obvious answer) would be why idiomatic clojure uses atoms rather than modifying vars' root bindings when state _does_ need to be changed -- answer is a little more subtle, coming down to performance and futureproofing (semantics of atoms are better-defined, thus less likely to be changed in ways that break things)

Comment: Agreed, in retrospect the defect is painfully obvious. The target audience for this question are Clojure newbies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using def inside a function body is not idiomatic, sort-of-but-not-explicitly undefined behavior, and considering the way vars are implemented, using `(dotimes .. (def ..))` is quite possibly slower than using `(loop ... (recur ...))`, especially when you're using basic types, like numbers, and type-hints.

The main reason not to do this kind of "dynamic" modification of vars, is that it complicates your code for no good reason. Some much more idiomatic combination of loop/recur and transients should under normal circumstances get you as good a performance as you can get out of clojure. And it will still be thread-safe, predictable and readable.

Edit: as a concrete defect: your example code does not work correctly when called from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Does not work correctly because def is bound to the namespace, not to the scope of the function, correct?

Comment: Because vars are bound to a namespace, and `def` binds to the "root" value of a var. See also [the documentation for `binding` and `def`](http://clojure.org/vars).

Answer (score 10):

If you try to run this code in parallel then the race conditions can
result in it  **silently producing wrong answers**

first run it on it's own:

```
core> (factorial-using-do-dotimes 10)
3628800
```

then run two copies but let the fast one finish well in advance:

```
core> (do (future (do (java.lang.Thread/sleep 5) 
                      (factorial-using-do-dotimes  1200))) 
          (factorial-using-do-dotimes 10))
3628800
```

then run them closer together:

```
core> (do (future (do (java.lang.Thread/sleep 1) 
                      (factorial-using-do-dotimes 1200))) 
          (factorial-using-do-dotimes 10))
3628800
```

then run them at the same time:

```
core> (do (future (do (java.lang.Thread/sleep 0) 
                      (factorial-using-do-dotimes 1200))) 
          (factorial-using-do-dotimes 10))
54698277723986154311681531904000000N
```

which is not the answer to either of the factorials being run.
(factorial-using-do-dotimes 1200) is 3176 digits long

and the answer comes out wrong.

note: I changed the factorial-using-do-dotimes function to use `*'` instead of `*` so I could run it on a bigger example to make the timing easier to hit in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Rebinding a def can have unpredictable results in an environment that requires synchronization. Consider using refs, atoms, or agents, if you need to modify state.

You can accumulate values in a for loop like so

```
(defn chk-key-present-in-sos
  ""
  [mapped-sos cmp-key cmp-seq-vals]
  (if (seq-of-maps? mapped-sos)
    (for [mapped-row mapped-sos
        :let [matched-rows mapped-row]
        :when (chk-one-val-present mapped-row cmp-key cmp-seq-vals)]
      matched-rows)
    nil))
```

You can use reduce to produce a final result.

```
(defn key-pres?
"This function accepts a value (cmp-val) and a vector of vectors
(parsed output from clojure-csv) and returns the match value
back if found and nil if not found.

Using reduce, the function searches every vector row to see
if cmp-val is at the col-idx location in the vector."

[cmp-val cmp-idx csv-data]
   (reduce
       (fn [ret-rc csv-row]
          (if (= cmp-val (nth csv-row col-idx nil))
            (conj ret-rc cmp-val)))
       []
       csv-data))
```

And you can use `into` to accumulate.

Finally, you can always use recursion and let the termination step return the
accumulated Fibonacci value.